# Duplicate Command line input to text file

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

I'm trying to write STDIN to a file, that will be read by another program.

Thus I was wondering if it is possible to duplicate the cmd.exe input to a file and if so, how might I accomplish it?

Comment: Something alike to [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)?  In fact, I can't understand what you are asking for. Please [edit] your question and provide more info according to [ask].

Comment: I thought the question pretty straight forward. I want to capture the keyboard input and write it to a text file.

Comment: You mean like a keystroke logger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to capture the command input and write it to a text file using this command.

```
type con > foo.txt | myprogram.bat
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824178/how-do-you-redirect-standard-input-to-a-file-in-the-windows-command-line